# How to define an environment with a colored tikz node included

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, environments

I would like to define a new environment like

```
\begin{mybox}
  some text
\end{mybox}
```

that would automatically expand to something like

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[fill=red!0.5] {some text};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I tried to define an environment with the following code in the preamble:

```
\newenvironment{mybox}{\begin{tikzpicture}\node[fill=red!0.5]\bgroup}{\egroup;\end{tikzpicture}}
```

but the color option is not fully working. If `fill=red` is used it works correctly, but if a mixed color like `fill=red!0.5` it doesn't.
What can be done to mix colors?

**EDIT:** The questions contains an error. It should be `red!50` instead of `red!0.5`. Anyway, the answers below can be helpful as alternatives to generate a colorful text box.

Comment: `\bgroup` is not the same as `{` and can not be used to delimit a macro argument Th eargumnet to `\node in your version is not `{some text}` but _just_ `\bgroup`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Blend values are between `0` and `100`. In this context, `0.5` is very close to zero. So `red!0.5` is very close to `white`. ;-)

Comment: @Paul Gaborit: You are right, silly me! I should have used `red!50` instead of `red!0.5`.

Comment: @David Carlisle: I followed [http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros#Unmatched_braces](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros#Unmatched_braces) which says that `\bgroup` and `{` are synonyms and recommends its use precisely in this situation.

Comment: @Miguel well don't believe everything you read on the internet:-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems to me that `fill=red!0.5` isn't distinguishable from white...

Anyway, for these kind of environment definitions, `\NewEnviron` from the [`environ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/environ) package can be useful.

```
\NewEnviron{mybox}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}%
    \node[fill=red!10]{\BODY};%
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

Note that I've changed `red!0.5` to `red!10` to make it distinguishable.

In the following MWE I've also left your definition and it seems to work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tikz}

\NewEnviron{mybox}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}%
    \node[fill=red!10]{\BODY};%
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newenvironment{oldmybox}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}\node[fill=red!10]\bgroup%
}{%
  \egroup;\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}Hello\end{mybox}

\begin{oldmybox}Hello\end{oldmybox}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[fill=red!10]{Hello};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want your environment be expanded in a tikzpicture, I'll delete my answer but if you want an environment to produce some colorful box, `\tcbox` command from [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) can help you. Next code shows how to define `\myboxcommand` or environment `myboxenv` which outputs will be like a `\node[fill]` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{myboxcommand}{nobeforeafter, tcbox raise base,
arc=0pt, outer arc=0pt, colback=red!10, boxsep=0pt,
boxrule=0pt, left=.3333em, right=.3333em, top=.3333em, bottom=.3333em}

\newtcolorbox{myboxenv}{nobeforeafter,capture=hbox,tcbox raise base,
arc=0pt, outer arc=0pt, colback=red!10, boxsep=0pt,
boxrule=0pt, left=.3333em, right=.3333em, top=.3333em, bottom=.3333em}

\begin{document}

\myboxcommand{Hello}

\begin{myboxenv}
Hello
\end{myboxenv}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[anchor=base,fill=red!10]{Hello};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]